Spline Road in spiral connecting points transformation
I need to transform spline in spiral from point transform to next point transform. Is there a better idea how to do it without spiral node?


Could you detail what are your inputs ? Control points at both ends, with position and tangent ? Number of turns ? Spiral radius ?

Hi, in more details it should go from transform red arrow to next red arrow with given number of turns. Somekind of Interpolation from given start transform to end transform.

And i want to meansion it should be build without spiral node.

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
Results

This view illustrates the achieved spiral with user-defined parameters set such that there are 2 turns and 200 points along the curve.
Resources
Blender file: 

Mathematics
Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be the starting and ending control points of a BezierCurve, and $\vec{t_1}$ and $\vec{t_2}$ the oriented unit vectors tangent to this curve in $B_1$ and $B_2$ respectively.  It is assumed that $\vec{t_1}$ and $\vec{t_2}$ are not collinear.

This view shows in Edit Mode the original spline control points and tangents. The root of the blue cone is located at $B_1$ and its tip is aligned with $\vec{t_1}$. The red cone visualises $B_2$ and $\vec{t_2}$.
1. Projection
$(B_1, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$ are defining a plane in which is sought the circle from which the spiral is developed. The unit normal to this plane, labelled $\vec{n}$, oriented from $B_1$ to $B_2$ is computed as:
$$
\vec{n} = \frac{\vec{t_1} \times \vec{t_2}}{\|\vec{t_1} \times \vec{t_2}\|}
$$
With $i=1,2$, let $M_i$ be the projection along $\vec{n}$ of $B_i$ into the plane $(B_1, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$. By construction, $M_1=B_1$. $M_2$ is computed as:
$$
\overrightarrow{M_1M_2} = \overrightarrow{B_1B_2} -
\left( \overrightarrow{B_1B_2} \cdot \vec{n}\right) \vec{n}
$$

This view shows the plane $(B_1, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$ in blue, and the plane $(B_2, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$ in red. $M_1$ and $M_2$ are rendered as cubes. The white cone visualized the vector $\left( \overrightarrow{B_1B_2} \cdot \vec{n}\right) \vec{n}$.
2. Bisector
Let $I$ be the intersection of lines $(M_1, \vec{t_1}$) and $(M_2, \vec{t_2}$). Introducing the local coordinates $(\lambda, \mu)$, $I$ is defined by:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\overrightarrow{M_1I} & = & \lambda \vec{t_1} \\
\overrightarrow{IM_2} & = & \mu \vec{t_2}
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
Consequently:
$$
\overrightarrow{M_1M_2} \times \vec{t_2} = 
\left( \lambda \vec{t_1} + \mu \vec{t_2} \right) \times \vec{t_2}
$$
yielding:
$$
\lambda = \frac{\left( \overrightarrow{M_1M_2} \times \vec{t_2} \right) \cdot \left( \vec{t_1} \times \vec{t_2}\right)}
{\|\vec{t_1} \times \vec{t_2}\|^2}
$$
Let $\vec{b}$ be the unit vector align with the bisector of the angle $(\widehat{M_1,I,M_2})$, computed as:
$$
\vec{b} = \frac{\vec{t_2} - \vec{t_1}}{\| \vec{t_2} - \vec{t_1} \|}
$$

This "top" view is aligned with $\vec{n}$. The cyan lines visualize lines $(M_1, \vec{t_1}$) and $(M_2, \vec{t_2}$). The root of the yellow cone is located at their crossing in $I$ and its tip is aligned with $\vec{b}$.
3. Tangent circles
A point along the line $(I, \vec{b})$ is the centre of a circle tangent simultaneously to the lines $(M_1, \vec{t_1}$) and $(M_2, \vec{t_2}$). With $i=1,2$, let $C_i$ be the centre of such a circle tangent to the line $(M_i, \vec{t_i}$) in $M_i$. Let $\vec{n_i}$ be the unit vector aligned with $\overrightarrow{M_iC_i}$, computed as:
$$
\vec{n_i} = \vec{n} \times \vec{t_i}
$$
Introducing the local coordinates $(\lambda_i, \mu_i)$, $C_i$ is defined by:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\overrightarrow{IC_i} & = & \lambda_i \vec{b} \\
\overrightarrow{M_iC_i} & = & \mu_i \vec{n_i}
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
Consequently:
$$
\overrightarrow{M_iI} \times \vec{b} = 
\left( \mu_i \vec{n_i} - \lambda_i \vec{b} \right) \times \vec{b}
$$
yielding:
$$
\mu_i = \frac{\left( \overrightarrow{M_iI} \times \vec{b} \right) \cdot \left( \vec{n_i} \times \vec{b}\right)}
{\|\vec{n_i} \times \vec{b}\|^2}
$$

This view shows in blue (resp. red) the circle tangent in $M_1$ (resp. $M_2$). The root of the associated cone is located at $C_1$ (resp. $C_2$) and its tip is aligned with $-\vec{n_1}$ (resp. $-\vec{n_2}$).
4. Circle
It is to notice that $\mu_i$ is the radius of the circle centred on $C_i$ tangent simultaneously to the lines $(M_1, \vec{t_1}$) and $(M_2, \vec{t_2}$). Let $\mu$ be the smallest radius between $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. Let $C$ be the centre of the associated circle (i.e. $C=C_1$ if $\mu_1 \lt \mu_2$, $C=C_2$ otherwise).
With $i=1,2$, let $P_i$ be the point where the circle of centre $C$ and radius $\mu$ is tangent to the line $(M_i, \vec{t_i}$). $P_i$ is defined by:
$$
\overrightarrow{CP_i} = -\mu \vec{n_i}
$$
yielding:
$$
\overrightarrow{M_1P_i} = \overrightarrow{M_1C}-\mu \vec{n_i}
$$
Let points $J$ and $K$ define the diameter of the circle of centre $C$ and radius $\mu$, along the line $(I, \vec{b})$. These are defined by:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\overrightarrow{CJ} & = & -\mu \vec{b} \\
\overrightarrow{CK} & = & +\mu \vec{b}
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
yielding:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\overrightarrow{M_1J} & = & \overrightarrow{M_1C}-\mu \vec{b} \\
\overrightarrow{M_1K} & = & \overrightarrow{M_1C}+\mu \vec{b}
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

This view displays as ico-spheres $P_1$ in blue and $P_2$ in red. $C$ is rendered as the yellow ico-sphere at the centre of the circle of radius $\mu=\mu_1$. $J$ is the ico-sphere closest to the yellow cone root ; $K$ is the one closest to this cone tip.
5. Arcs
In the plane $(B_1, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$, let $\mathcal{A}_J$ be the arc connecting $P_1$ to $P_2$ with $J$ as middle point. Let $\mathcal{A}_K$ be the arc connecting $P_2$ to $P_1$ with $K$ as middle point. $\mathcal{A}_J$ and $\mathcal{A}_K$ define the circle from which the spiral is developed. Let $N$ be the number of turns of the spiral. $N+1$ copies of $\mathcal{A}_J$ and $N$ copies of $\mathcal{A}_K$ made the whole spiral.

The green lines in this view show the limits of both arcs, $\mathcal{A}_J$ and $\mathcal{A}_K$.
6. Elongation
Assuming these copies are joined into a single curve, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are at both ends after merging. Assuming this curve length is evenly sampled, the resulting points $Q_i$ are distributed along the direction of $\vec{n}$ to stretch the spiral between the planes $(B_1, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$ and $(B_2, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$. Let $\nu_i \in [0:1]$ be the factor of point $Q_i$. The simplest offset along $\vec{n}$ to apply, labelled $\vec{\delta^n}$, can be defined as:
$$
\vec{\delta^n}(\nu_i) = \nu_i \left( \overrightarrow{B_1B_2} \cdot \vec{n} \right) \vec{n}
$$
With $i=1,2$, let $N_i$ be the projection along $\vec{n}$ of $P_i$ into the plane $(B_i, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$. By construction, $N_1=P_1$. $N_2$ is computed as:
$$
\overrightarrow{P_2N_2} = \overrightarrow{M_2B_2} 
$$
Consequently:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\overrightarrow{B_1N_1} & = & \overrightarrow{M_1P_1} \\
\overrightarrow{B_2N_2} & = & \overrightarrow{M_2P_2}
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
For $\nu = 0$ or $1$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcccl}
\overrightarrow{OP_1} + \vec{\delta^n}(0) & = & \overrightarrow{OP_1} + 0 & = &
\overrightarrow{ON_1} \\
\overrightarrow{OP_2} + \vec{\delta^n}(1) & = & \overrightarrow{OP_2} + \left( \overrightarrow{B_1B_2} \cdot \vec{n} \right) \vec{n} & = &
\overrightarrow{ON_2}
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
So $N_1$ and $N_2$ are at both ends of the curve after applying the offset $\vec{\delta^n}$.

In this view, with $i=1,2$, $P_i$ are rendered as ico-spheres and $N_i$ as cylinders. The white cone visualises the vectors $\overrightarrow{M_2B_2} = \overrightarrow{P_2N_2}$.
7. Shear
It is to notice that $\overrightarrow{B_iN_i}$, with $i=1,2$, is collinear to $\vec{t_i}$. Consequently, the offset $\vec{\delta^t}$ defined as follows is perpendicular to $\vec{n}$.
$$
\vec{\delta^t}(\nu_i) = -\left\{ (1-\nu_i) \overrightarrow{B_1N_1} + \nu_i \overrightarrow{B_2N_2} \right\}
$$
For $\nu = 0$ or $1$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcccl}
\overrightarrow{ON_1} + \vec{\delta^t}(0) & = & \overrightarrow{ON_1} - \overrightarrow{B_1N_1} & = &
\overrightarrow{OB_1} \\
\overrightarrow{ON_2} + \vec{\delta^t}(1) & = & \overrightarrow{ON_2} - \overrightarrow{B_2N_2} & = &
\overrightarrow{OB_2}
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
Thus applying the offset $\vec{\delta^t}$ brings the end points of the curve (i.e. $N_1$ and $N_2$) to the initial control points position (i.e. $B_1$ and $B_2$). Between the planes $(B_1, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$ and $(B_2, \vec{t_1}, \vec{t_2})$, a linear combination of both translations is applied for such a simple definition of $\vec{\delta^t}$.

This view illustrates how the end point of the curve touching the red plane is translated from $N_2$, at the cylinder position, to $B_2$, at the root of the cone, while its end point touching the blue plane is unaffected because $N_1=B_1$.

GeometryNodes Graph






Complex but works

Fewer user defined parameters, higher mathematical complexity...

Wow. That's comprehensive! I can't get to it because too preoccupied AFK at the moment.  just thinking.. given a vertical spiral-primitive through the given theta in the given h, would a linear mix between the that spiral,  duplicated,  A: aligned to entry, B: aligned to exit (at its other end), by factor h, do all this maths for you? (You might not even need h)
